# Repository signature for asp.net core 2.1 controller action return types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to modify my Asp.net Core 2.1 project to use the new controller action return types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type)

The controller example they give is:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public ActionResult<Product> GetById(int id)
{
    if (!_repository.TryGetProduct(id, out var product))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return product;
}
```

However what does the repository signature for this method look like?

if I try:

```
public async Task<Product> TryGetProduct(int id)
```

then I get an error that there is no repository method that takes 2 arguments.

But if I try:

```
public async Task<Product> TryGetProduct(int id, out var product)
```

then I get:

Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

Comment: It means your method signature can't have the `async` keyword.  You can still return a `Task<Product>` so that it's awaitable but you can't do any awaiting within the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature would be

```
public interface IRepository
{
    bool TryGetProduct(int id, out Product product);
}
```

And in the implementation, If your database has a record for the `Id` value, you will set that to the Product object and return `true`, else `false`.

Something like this (*not tested*)

```
public class Repository: IRepository
{
    YourDbContext yourDbContext;
    // to do : Initialize yourDbContext via constructor injection

    public bool TryGetProduct(int id, out Product product)
    {           
        var p = yourDbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
        if (p != null)
        {
            product = p;
            return true;
        }
        product = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem though is that you lose async operators for your controller actions

Comment: Because it works and it's what I'm going to use, but there appears to be a downside to it unfortunatley

Answer (score 1):

To keep the async task functionality you can do this.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<bool> TryGetProduct(int id, out Product product);
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Task<bool> TryGetProduct(int id, out Product product)
    {
        product = _db.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        return Task.FromResult(product != null);
    }
}
```

Then in the controller.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetById(int id)
{
    // await 
    if (!await _repository.TryGetProduct(id, out var product))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(product);
}
```